# How to display selected value and image in edit page to perform update operation using laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello,
I am new learner in Laravel and my first post in Stackoverflow so applogy to me for my mistake and English language.

I can create a project shoppingcart & perform CRUD operation where create product information such as product name, brand, description, price & image. I can done create & read operation easily. Below my product list that can be show in browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2lWb.png)

When I click edit button browser can show like that below image to perform edit operation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m7we.png)

where brand name & image can't shown edit product form

My productController code below like that

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\brand;
 use App\Product;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class productController extends Controller
 {
  public function index(){



    $product = DB::table('products')
        ->join('brands','products.brandID','=','brands.brandID')
        -> select('products.*','brands.brandName')
        ->get();



    return view('admin.product.productList',compact('product'));
}


   public function create()
   {
    $product = brand::pluck('brandName','brandID');

    return view('admin.product.createProduct',compact('product'));
   }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {

    // image upload

    $product = $request->except('image');

    $image = $request->image;


    if ($image) {
        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        $image->move('images', $imageName);

        $product['image'] = $imageName;
    }

    Product::create($product);

    return view('admin.product.productList', compact('product'));
 }

 public function show($id)
 {
    $product = Product::find($id);


    return view('admin.product.editProduct',compact('product'));
}


 public function edit($id)
 {


 }

 public function delete($id){

    $product= Product::find($id);

    $data=$product->delete();




    return view('admin.product.productList',compact('data'));
}
}
```

my editProduct.blade file code below like that

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')



   <div class="container" align="center">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
       </div>
    </div>



   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
           <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Edit Product
               </div>
           <div class="panel-body">
               <form action="edit" class="form-horizontal" method="POST>    


           {{csrf_field()}}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Name :</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{!! $product->productName !!}" name="name" required autofocus>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Brand :</label>

                       <div class="col-md-6">

                           <select name=" " class="form-control" >

                               <option>  
                               </option>

                           </select>

                       </div>
                   </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description" class="col-md-4 control-label">Description:</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="description"  class="form-control" name="description" value="{!! $product->description !!}" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price" class="col-md-4 control-label">Price:</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="price" value="{!! $product->price !!}" class="form-control" name="price" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 control-label">Image:</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="image" type="file" value="{!! $product->image !!}" class="btn-btn-default" name="image" value="Upload" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                ADD
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`@endsection`

Here, brand name can be selected by HTML select attribute and value get another model Brand & the data can be retrieve from Brand model using join query which is included productController index method.

So how can I show brand name & image to edit in the editProduct blade file. Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways, here's 1 way.

In your controller.

```
 public function edit($id)
 {
        $product = Product::find($id);

        $data = [
             'product_info' => $product 
        ];

        return view('your.edit.view.here', $data);

 }
```

And inside your view, inside the FORM Tag, do the looping.

```
@foreach($product_info as $info)
  // data info here
  <input id="description"  value="{{ $product->description }}" required>
@endforeach
```

EDIT::

Use [Laravel Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption), you need it especially web apps like shopping cart.

```
URL:: http://localhost:8000/product/show/encrypted_id_here
public function show($id) {
   $id = decrypt($id);
}
```

Comment: This is not exact answere

Comment: Why? What's your answer?

Comment: I discuss in my post. I will get only two specific field which are selected value & image to edit. You also see attach image